# Symfony 6 global functions.php causes exception

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I get

> Expected to find class "App\Helper\dj_functions" in file "/home/myuser/IdeaProjects/myproject/symfony/src/Helper/dj_functions.php" while importing services from resource "../src/", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/myproject/symfony/config/services.yaml (which is being imported from "/home/myuser/IdeaProjects/myproject/symfony/src/Kernel.php").

where dj_functions.php is my global functions helper.

clearing the cache via `php bin/console cache:clear`

actually fixes the issue temporarily

Answer (score 0):

exclude from auto detection

services.yaml

```
App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Helper/dj_functions.php'
```